# What have I done wrong in the following derivation of energy stored in a capacitor

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

What have I done wrong in the following derivation of energy stored in a capacitor.

If you want to charge a capacitor you've to remove electrons from one conductor and carry them to other conductor. Suppose at some intermediate stage charge on the positive conductor is $ne$(where $n$ is some positive integer and $e=1.6\times 10^{-19}\ coulombs$) then the potential difference between the conductors is $$V=V_{+}-V_{-}=-\int_{-}^{+}\vec{E} \cdot d\vec{l}=\frac{ne}{C}$$ where $C$ is the capacitance of the arrangement and $V_{+}$ and $V_{-}$ are the potentials of positive and negative conductors respectively.

The work done in moving one electron from positive conductor to negative conductor is
 $$W\left|_{+}^{-}\right.=-e\left[V_{-}-V_{+}\right]=-e\frac{-ne}{C}=\frac{ne^2}{C}$$
 Suppose you are charging the positive conductor to a final charge $Q=Ne$, then the total work done is
\begin{align}
W
&=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \frac{ne^2}{C}=\frac{e^2}{C}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}n=\frac{e^2}{C}\left[\frac{(N-1)N}{2}\right]=\frac{N^2e^2}{2C}-\frac{Ne^2}{2C}
\\ & =\frac{Q^2}{2C}-\frac{Qe}{2C}.
\end{align}
However, this is in contrast to the usual result of electromagnetism textbooks, $W=\frac{Q^2}{2C}$. Is this calculation wrong?

Comment: See [check-my-work questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic)

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes or the close-votes on this question. This is a perfectly reasonable (and quite insightful) conceptual question on the nature of the usual approximations in electromagnetism textbooks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your work is correct, as is your expression for $W=Q^2/2C - Qe/2C$. The reason it doesn't match the usual expression, which drops that second term, is that normally the calculation is done using one infinitesimal bit of charge at a time, and then integrating. In other words, it corresponds to your result in the limit of $e/Q\to 0$ - and indeed your solution reduces to the standard result in that limit.

Of course, your solution is in many ways the correct one, since charge is ultimately quantized, and there is no such thing in the lab as an infinitesimal amount of charge (not even in the way that you *can* speak of, for example, an infinitesimal displacement, which is really code for a finite but arbitrarily small change in position). You have found that the quantization of charge means that the standard result can only ever be an approximation.

The reason we use it is because it is normally a very good approximation. A standard (smallish) capacitor in a circuit board will have, say, about a picofarad of capacitance, and it will be subjected to about a volt of potential difference, so it will hold about a picocoulomb of charge:
$$
Q\cong 10^{-12}\:\mathrm{C} \approx 10^7e.
$$
This means that $e/Q$ is of the order of $10^{-7}$, so the usual expression $W=Q^2/2C$ is accurate to about seven significant figures. Corrections to this order are normally not something that we fret about, so we can usually just drop the term. If we *do* want 7+ significant figure accuracy on that energy, then we have a number of other things to worry about: a sufficiently accurate value for the capacitance, for instance, as well as a number of residual capacitances and inductances all over the lab, among many other effects that might contribute in any given situation.

And, as you'll have guessed by now, these charge quantization effects do become relevant if your circuit is small enough that you care about single-electron effects. However, if you're in that regime then odds are that you need to be doing things quantum mechanically to begin with, and that's a whole other ball game, with the energy itself being replaced by [a more complicated object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_(quantum_mechanics)), just for starters.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. For obtaining a more accurate expression shouldn't we consider the work functions of the conductors.

Comment: @AswinMadhu For obtaining a more accurate expression there is a whole host of different things you might need to consider, and the analysis will go on a case-by-case scenario. Everything contributes, but not everything contributes equally - the art is in knowing which correction kicks in first, but that one depends on the situation.

Comment: @AswinMadhu: I would think that the work functions of the metals would cancel out:  in other words, the energy required to extract to "lift an electron out" of one metal surface would be compensated by an equal amount of energy liberated when the electron "fell back in" to the other surface.

Comment: @Michael Seifert: Work functions of metals will be cancelled out only when the two conductors are of same type (same material)

Comment: @AswinMadhu The work functions are a red herring, because they change if the two metals are in contact. In essence, the work function is the difference between the Fermi energy and that of a free electron; however, if the two metals have different work functions (i.e. different Fermi energies) then when you put them into contact the electrons will migrate to the one with lower energy until the global Fermi level is equalized. This establishes an additional potential between the two electrodes called a [Volta potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volta_potential).

Comment: So, as I said: the reason that the textbook result is kept at that level of approximation is that you cannot proceed to a better description without knowing which other effect will kick in first, and that can (and does) come from a huge range of directions, depending on the situation. There's a bunch of things that come in between the first and the seventh significant figures, and this is not the place to catalogue them.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty : Can you give answer to the following question. http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/299051/on-what-basis-can-we-say-that-the-surface-charge-density-of-a-conductors-is-prop

Comment: @AswinMadhu A quick tip on site etiquette - this sort of contact isn't really seen with a good light here, unless folks have signed up [here](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1159/). Anyone can answer your question, i.e. more people than you realize and might attempt to contact.